# C3P0 - Single Connection with maxConnectionAge

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, c3p0

I am quite new to C3P0 & was reading some of its properties here : https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#unreturnedConnectionTimeout

I have a simple question about C3P0 from those who have used it - If i set both minPoolSize = 1 & maxPoolSize = 1 & maxConnectionAge = 30 secs.

Will C3P0 connection destroy the connection after 30 secs & acquire a new connection Or
It will keep the same connection open?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, yes, but to know for sure, you will probably have to debug the code. You could try to set a break point in the connection constructor of your driver and let the timeout happen. Observe that the break point is hit to verify that it in fact works like that.

Answer (score 0):

A Connection older than `maxConnectionAge` will be destroyed and purged from the pool. This differs from `maxIdleTime` in that it refers to absolute age. Even a Connection which has not been much idle will be purged from the pool if it exceeds `maxConnectionAge`. Zero means no maximum absolute age is enforced